# Cassandra JRE 8 Two JDKs

Tags: java, macos, cassandra

So I have the following setup for Java on my Mac OSX Mavericks:

```
$ java -version

java version "1.8.0_05"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_05-b13)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.5-b02, mixed mode)
```

When starting Cassandra via:

```
$ cassandra
```

I get this error statement:

```
    objc[4347]: Class JavaLaunchHelper is implemented in both 
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_05.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java and 
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_05.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/libinstrument.dylib. 
One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
Fehler: Ausnahme von Agent ausgelöst : java.lang.NullPointerException
```

What can I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The agent NullPointer exception comes up if Cassandra is already running on that node and is unrelated to the Java warning.

Check jps to see if you have a C* process already running.

```
$ ps auwx | grep cassandra
$ sudo kill <pid>
```

http://www.datastax.com/docs/1.0/references/start_stop_ref